# how to execute qadd command in inline assembly in arm?

Tags: android, c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I got error when i tried to compile inline assembly with `qadd` command.

> Error: cannot honor width suffix -- `qadd r7,r7,r1'

I know that `qadd` is supported in  [ARMv5TE](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihidceh.html)

> These ARM instructions are available in ARMv6 and above, and E
>   variants of ARMv5T.

C/asm code:

```
inline int __qadd(int a, int b) {
    __asm__ (
            "qadd %0, %1, %2" : "=r" (a) : "r" (a), "r" (b));
    return a;
}
```

My cpu features is:

```
LOGI("__ARM_ARCH__='%d'", __ARM_ARCH__);
LOGI("__ARM_HAVE_5TE='%d'", __ARM_HAVE_5TE);
```

Output:

> __ARM_ARCH__='5'
>   __ARM_HAVE_5TE='1'

I have next compiler flags:

> LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c99 -ffast-math -march=armv5te

Besides i have tried replace `add` instead of `qadd` - nicely works but with `qadd` code not compiles.

What i'm doing wrong? Who can provide worked example of qadd command in assembly?

Comment: Try the extra compiler switches - `-mtune=arm1136jf-s -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp`?

Comment: @t0mm13b In android.mk `EXTRA_CFLAGS += -mtune=arm1136jf-s -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp`, but no luck, still occurs error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution here [No qsort_r for Android (or how to disable force Thumb to use CLZ in Android ARM code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033017/no-qsort-r-for-android-or-how-to-disable-force-thumb-to-use-clz-in-android-arm)

> In your Android.mk file, add ".arm" to the filenames and they will get
>   compiled as ARM mode instead of Thumb mode (e.g. sort.c.arm). I've had
>   mixed Thumb/ARM code in an Android native library and it worked fine.

Question is closed.